# Validating multiple select boxes with the jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So I've run into a bit of an issue while working with the jQuery Validation Plugin. I have 3 select tags next to each other so a user can enter their birthday. How do I go about having 1 validation message for 3 select tags? I've heard maybe a custom rule can be done?

Here's the HTML and I've included a jsfiddle.

```
<form id="commentForm" action="" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="month">Birthday:</label>
    <select name="month" class="required select">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option>Jan</option>
        <option>Feb</option>
    </select>
    <select name="day" class="required select">
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" class="required select">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option>1990</option>
        <option>1991</option>
    </select>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button">
</form>​
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/atLV4/) is an example of what's currently going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `group` option to group together fields so that one error message is shown for the group. You can then place that one error message where you desire using the `errorPlacement` option:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    groups: {
        birthday: "month day year"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var name = element.prop("name");
        if (name === "month" || name === "day" || name === "year") {
            error.insertAfter("select[name='year']");
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/atLV4/3/

Comment: +1, nice answer, can you set a custom message like `These fields are required` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Thanks! Yep, you would populate the `messages` option that you can supply to `validate`. You'd have to provide an error message for each field within the group though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked great! Apparently copying the js from jsfiddle causes a `Syntax Error: illegal character` sometimes. Took me forever to fix that. Just had to type the whole thing by hand.

Comment: @Sean: Glad to help! Sorry about the illegal character issue, it is annoying